# error building-a-monorepo-with-gradle with pack build

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, buildpack

Trying to build monorepo-with-gradle with packeto build pack, while running the pipeline unable create .[jw]ar
Got below error
13:43:57        BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 25s
13:43:57        18 actionable tasks: 15 executed, 3 up-to-date
13:43:57
13:43:57  unable to invoke layer creator
13:43:57  unable to contribute application layer
13:43:57  unable to resolve artifacts
13:43:57  unable to find any built artifacts for pattern(s):
13:43:57  build/libs/*.[jw]ar. If this is unexpected, please try setting `rootProject.name` in `settings.gradle` or add a project.toml file and exclude the `build/` directory. For details see https://buildpacks.io/docs/app-developer-guide/using-project-descriptor/.
13:43:57  ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1
13:44:00  ERROR: failed to build: executing lifecycle: failed with status code: 51

Test github repo:https://github.com/rajkumarvenkatasamy/building-a-monorepo-with-gradle/tree/main

13:43:57        BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 25s
13:43:57        18 actionable tasks: 15 executed, 3 up-to-date
13:43:57
13:43:57  unable to invoke layer creator
13:43:57  unable to contribute application layer
13:43:57  unable to resolve artifacts
13:43:57  unable to find any built artifacts for pattern(s):
13:43:57  build/libs/*.[jw]ar. If this is unexpected, please try setting `rootProject.name` in `settings.gradle` or add a project.toml file and exclude the `build/` directory. For details see https://buildpacks.io/docs/app-developer-guide/using-project-descriptor/.
13:43:57  ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1
13:44:00  ERROR: failed to build: executing lifecycle: failed with status code: 51